# Styled component generate same css class with different conditions

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I have these styles:-

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const H4 = css`
  font-family: "Futura";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #3a786a;
`;
const H3 = css`
  font-size: 24px;
`;

const Span = css`
  font-size: 16px;
`;

export const Typography = styled.div`
  #widgetStyles & {
    ${(props) => {
      switch (props.variant) {
        case "h4":
          return H4;
        case "h3":
          return H3;
        case "body1":
          return Span;
        default:
          return css`
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #010101;
          `;
      }
    }}
  }
`;
```

Whenever i tried calling the Typography component with different variations Styled-components generate same css class. Which creates confliction between styles.

This is how i am calling the above defined component with different variations:-

```
<Typography variant="h4">{label}</Typography>

<Typography variant="h3">{label}</Typography>
```

But it generates the output with same class:-

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `styled-components` generates different classes but the first class is same and other class are different, as you can see in `h4` and `h3` tag, could you please change `#widgetStyles &` to `#widgetStyles &&`, as you can see the below code.

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const H4 = css`
  font-family: "Futura";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: #3a786a;
`;
const H3 = css`
  font-size: 24px;
`;

const Span = css`
  font-size: 16px;
`;

export const Typography = styled.div`
  #widgetStyles && {
    ${(props) => {
      switch (props.variant) {
        case "h4":
          return H4;
        case "h3":
          return H3;
        case "body1":
          return Span;
        default:
          return css`
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #010101;
          `;
      }
    }}
  }
`;
```

Comment: nice, good to know.

But i can't remove the id as this is needed. This whole thing is a widget and we are wrapping all styles under the #Id widgetStyles so that it wont effect the other styles on the page where it'll be integrated.

Comment: Hi @JA9 I have updated the answer, could you please try.

Comment: nice, this is working now